# Заполнить SVG-карту "шумом"

Tags: javascript, svg, фильтры

Нужно сверстать вот такую карту c эффектом заполнения "шумом":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент получается вот такой вариант: https://codepen.io/Cheg/pen/mpQzoO

```
.branches-map__region {
    fill:#e5e5e5;
    stroke:#fff;
    stroke-width:.5px;
}
```

Как видно, точки на карте получаются разноцветными, а нужно, чтобы они были в цветовом диапазоне "фона".

Как такое можно реализовать?

**Уточнение:**
Цветные сектора (красные и светло-серые) - не hover-эффект, а просто статичные цвета для данных регионов.

Comment: плюс за хороший вопрос

Answer (score 5):

Эффект шума можно получить несколькими приемами.

Приведу два из них:

- С помощью комбинации различных SVG фильтров, но применение фильтров,
  особенно фильтров размытия Гаусса и фильтра турбуленсе сильно
  нагружает процессор.

**LeaVerou** удалось найти удачное сочетание фильтров для создания [эффекта шума](https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/3206117), но она предупреждает о возможных проблемах с производительностью

> SVG noise (Warning: Might be slow!)

- Второй путь,- создание скриншота с образца шума и использование
  получившейся картинки в качестве паттерна для заполнения объекта

Ниже в примере показаны эти два способа для создания эффекта шума:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  <defs>
<filter id="noise">
 <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency=".7" />
 <feComponentTransfer>
         <feFuncR type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-1"/>
         <feFuncG type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-1"/>
         <feFuncB type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-1"/>
 </feComponentTransfer>
 <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
 <feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 .3"/>
 </feComponentTransfer>
</filter> 
<pattern id="MapPattern"
             x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
             patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"
    patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" >
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlbBq.png" width="1" height="1"  />      
 </pattern>  
</defs>
<rect width="400" height="400" fill="#DBDBDB"  />
<text font-size="20" x="50" y="30" > Filter noise </text>
<rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" filter="url(#noise)" />   

<text font-size="20" x="210" y="30" > Pattern noise </text>
<rect x="200" y="42" width="120" height="120" stroke="white" fill="url(#MapPattern)" />

</svg>
```

*У обоих способов есть преимущества и недостатки:*

- фильтр сильно нагружает "железо" ПК, но заполнение объекта более
  равномерное.
- Заполнение паттерном объектов может выглядеть неравномерно  из-за
  разного размера и масштабирования, но не требует столько ресурсов производительности, как применение фильтров. Например на карте России сравните Красноярский край и любую из центральных областей.

  **Ниже пример карты России с техникой заполнения паттерном шума.**

[**Demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJvZLm)